# ¿Cómo puedo comparar variables en un mismo if frente a una sola condición en java?

Tags: java

necesito que mi programa me compare tres variables ingresadas por el usuario pero que si esas variables son mayores a 9 me salga por consola un error. Lo que intento es hacer lo siguiente, pero me aparece un error, acaso tengo todas que compararlas por independiente con && no hay alguna forma de simplificar esto como lo quiero hacer:

```
 if(digito3,digito4,digito5>9){
     System.out.println("Error");
 }
```

Comment: Pues si es con un &&

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sería con el operador & de la siguiente manera:
En el caso de que el error se muestre si las 3 son mayor a 9

```
if(digito3>9&&digito4>9&&digito5>9){
 System.out.println("Error");
}
```

En el caso de que el error se muestre si una de las 3 es mayor a 9

```
if(digito3>9||digito4>9||digito5>9){
 System.out.println("Error");
}
```